# my.cnf missing on all directories after new mysql installtion

Tags: mysql, centos, installation, my.cnf

Title says it all. I previously had mysql version 5.1 on my CENTOS 6 x86_64 OS. 
I attempted to remove mysql 5.1 and replace it with an install of mysql 5.6.

**Here is my uninstall process for mysql 5.1:**

```
yum remove mysql
yum remove mysql-devel
yum remove mysql-client

rpm -qa | grep -i mysql
rpm -e mysql --nodeps
```

**Here is my install process for mysql 5.6:**

I got three rpm's for mysql 5.6. `server`, `devel`, and `client` all `x86_64`.

`rpm -ivh` on all three rpm's in the order of `server` first, then `client` then `devel`.
`/usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'pass'`
`/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation`
`reboot`

I then went into my webmin admin panel to play around with some mysql settings and it told me my `/etc/my.cnf` file was missing. So I went into my server to look for the `my.cnf` file and I could not find it in its usual places.

So I attempted to run a `mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"` and I got three directories that it is searching for a `my.cnf` file. `/etc/my.cnf`, `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, and `~/.my.cnf`. I checked all three directories but I could not for the life of me find that file.. Now I went to my mysql home directory which is `/var/lib/mysql` to find the .cnf file but all I found was `auto.cnf`.

Does anyone have any ideas? Could I just download a my.cnf file and place it in one of those directories?

Comment: You need to specify where you obtained your RPMs.

Comment: from the mysql download site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the installation process doesn't create a `my.cnf` file for you then you merely need to create one yourself. Full documentation on the options is available on the MySQl web site. There's no magic with this stuff and MySQL will in most cases run with built-in defaults if it can't find an options file. Webmin (really, you use that?) gets a little precious about these things sometimes but that has nothing to do with MySQL. I recommend you learn to manage your system from the command line and get proper control.

Answer (score 8):

Run `rpm -ql MySQL-server`, I bet that you will see several default configuration files available in `/usr/share/mysql`. Just pick one and copy to `/etc`:

```
# cp /usr/share/mysql/my-(small|medium|large|huge).cnf /etc/
```