# MySQL not getting started on linux

Tags: linux, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [my.cnf missing on all directories after new mysql installtion](https://serverfault.com/questions/430598/my-cnf-missing-on-all-directories-after-new-mysql-installtion)

I need to run MySQL service for my linux 2.16 version with SUSE version 11 distribution.
Downloaded the following files and installed all the rpms as under:

```
MySQL-server-5.5.27-1.sles11.i586
MySQL-client-5.5.27-1.sles11.i586
MySQL-devel-5.5.27-1.sles11.i586
MySQL-shared-5.5.27-1.sles11.i586
MySQL-shared-compat-5.5.27-1.sles11.i586
```

There was no error during installation and I have confirmed the installed packages via:

```
rpm -qa|grep -i sql
```

But the server is not getting started when trying to execute through:

```
$> mysql
```

M getting the following as eror msg:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I have checked that in the */etc/init.d* location, only **mysql** entry is there instead of **mysqld**, is this the reason of the server startup error.

On googling for hours, I have also tried ./mysql start from the same location but getting the following output:

```
Starting MySQL..The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/ABC2-rahul.pid).
```

I am new to mysql, any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

I have cheked and found that some configuration files have been in the /usr/share/mysql loaction, and I have copied my-huge.cnf file to /etc location, any comments ?

Following is the content from the same my.cnf file:

```
[mysqld]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 384M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 512
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size = 32M

thread_concurrency = 8

log-bin=mysql-bin

server-id       = 1

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Comment: Just try `/etc/init.d/mysql start` and check the log files, usually in `/var/log/mysql`.

Comment: Thanks but on trying to start mysql, even m wondering why but there is not any log file for mysql in the location /etc/init.d !!

Comment: The right directory is /var/log, not /etc/init.d !

Comment: ya i have posted dat wrong in my above cmment, i have cheked but there isnt any log file created for mysql in d location /var/log !!

Comment: Please post the content of the file /etc/my.cnf

Comment: sory to say.. no such file created there !!

Comment: I think that you made a wrong installation. In the rpm's there are usually all the files. Try: rpm -q MySQL-server-5.5.27-1 --filesbypkg | grep my.cnf

Comment: @AndrewQ no output, tried dat also. But on checking with rpm -qa | grep -i sql it shows the installed mysql packages and also i have downloaded from mysql official download page, also installed successfully, but still error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks a lot like permission issues check that /var/lib/mysql is owned by the same user as the one running the mysql daemon.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your package is malformed or incomplete.

To solve this, create your own my.cnf file.

Verify that a 'mysql' user has been created. If not, create auser mysql and a group mysql.

In /etc create my.cnf with a minimal set of settings:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
port=3306

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

[client]
user=root
port=3306
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

This should be enough to keep mysqld up and running. of course, you have to add your settings.
Start the server using /etc/init.d/mysql start (or the command that your distro uses to start a service).

If the server starts, you have to create the root user (usually with 'mysqladmin -u root -p password' and 'mysqladmin -h hostname -u root -p password')